# AEM- Activating page references in node properties along with the page

Tags: aem, aem-6

I am working on AEM 6.2 and have created a custom replication module. I have some properties in my page's child nodes under jcr:content,whose values are the path field to another pages in the same website.
when I am activating a page, I need to activate the pages referenced in the properties too.
For example, my page path is "/content/project/family/subfamily/TestPage"
I need to activate a page path in the node property "pathVal" under 
"/content/project/family/subfamily/TestPage/abc123/jcr:content".
 How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by

> custom replication module

---

Writing a replication `Preprocessor` (see [docs](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/ref/javadoc/com/day/cq/replication/Preprocessor.html)) may be a way to go. The replication process collects all implementations of that interface using the whiteboard pattern and then cycles through them invoking each one of them.

```
@Component
@Service
public class ReferencedPagePreprocessor implements Preprocessor {

    @Reference
    private Replicator replicator;

    @Reference
    private ResourceResolverFactory resolverFactory;

    public void preprocess(ReplicationAction action, ReplicationOptions options)  {
        // some extra filtering to avoid the calculation if it's not the expected page type

        String resourcePath = action.getPath();
        ResourceResolver resolver = getResolver();
        Resource resource = resolver.resolve(resourcePath);
        String referencedResourcePath = resource.adaptTo(ValueMap.class).get("pathVal", String.class);

        replicator.replicate(resolver.adaptTo(Session.class), ReplicationActionType.ACTIVATE, referencedResourcePath);
    }

    private ResourceResolver getResolver() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Take also a look into a sample implementation in [ACS AEM Commons](https://github.com/Adobe-Consulting-Services/acs-aem-samples/blob/master/bundle/src/main/java/com/adobe/acs/samples/replication/impl/SampleReplicationPreprocessor.java)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly either you have implemented your own workflow process that activates the page or you would have followed the approach of `Preprocessor` as outlined by Mateusz Chromiński.

In case you have written your own workflow process that invokes `Replicator` API you could effectively add logic to get referenced paths and call activate on them using `Replicator` API